# Getting System Path or ProgramData Path in Kernel Code

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, filter-driver

I am Developing a file system filter driver .

I need the path for "C:\Windows" or "C:\Program Data" or I need an something like shgetfolderpath in kernel .So please help me out in this

Comment: Pick either C or C++

Comment: When your shell starts, get the special folder with your shgetfolderpath, or that knownFolder thingy, and communicate it to your driver.

Comment: The system directory (e.g. "Windows") is available as the "\SystemRoot" object link. The value of `%ProgramData%` isn't available as an object link. It gets loaded initially by wininit.exe from the "ProgramData" value in "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList". The default value is `"%SystemDrive%\ProgramData"`.